# Прокрутка материала PHP

Tags: php, html, javascript

Тут нашел картинку. [image]
<sub>(источник: [dnevnik.ru](http://static.dnevnik.ru/images/screens/680/marks.teacher.subject.png))</sub>

И возник вопрос, как можно сделать, чтобы прокрутка была не всего кода. Как тут ученики и их фамилии стоят на месте, а вот стрелка, где написаны уроки, как бы перелистывает на следующие даты.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это делается не на PHP, а средствами html, Java... Чем не лень в общем-то...
[Ajax Powered, Editable DHTML JavaScript DataGrid](http://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxGrid/) - неплохой пример реализации.

Answer (score 0):

Если в общих словах, делаете Ajax запрос на интересующую дату, потом подставляете пришедшие значения в таблицу.
Более простой способ - ahah: часть таблицы с датами - отдельная страница, запихнутая в Iframe. Проблема в том, что ahah в xhtml уже считается устаревшим.